# Class not found, using include_once in namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to use one of my classes in my namespace but I get a class not found error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ChatManager' not found in /var/www/soFitTest/chat/src/MyApp/Chat.php on line 17
```

Here is the code:

```
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

include_once __DIR__.'/ChatMananger.php';


    class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface 
    {
        protected $clients;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
            echo "new server is running";
            $chatManager = new \ChatMananger(1, 1);
        }
    }
```

My file structure is:

The code that I posted in the top of the page is found in `Chat.php`

The class `ChatMananger`is found in `ChatMananger.php`

[image]

The `ChatMananger.php` file:

```
<?php

require_once 'DBConnection.php';

    class ChatMananger
    {
         const DEFAULT_CHAT_SIZE = 5;
         const DEFAULT_CHAT_TYPE = 1;

         private $dbConnection;
         private $chatId;
         private $senderId;
         private $receiverId;
         private $type = ChatManager::DEFAULT_CHAT_TYPE;

          public function __construct($senderId, $receiverId)
          {   
           $this->dbConnection = DBConnection::getDBConnection();  

           $this->senderId = $senderId;
           $this->receiverId = $receiverId;     
           }

        public function getDBConnection()
        {
                return $this->dbConnection; 
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

I got things working in the `__construct`

```
<?php

namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

include_once __DIR__.'/ChatMananger.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/ChatConsts.php';
require_once '/var/www/libs/DBConnection.php';

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface 
{
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
        echo "new server is running";
        new ChatMananger(1, 1);
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later

        $querystring = $conn->WebSocket->request->getQuery();

        foreach ($querystring as $key => $value)
        {
            //echo PHP_EOL."key ".$key." value ".$value;

            if($key == "senderId")
                $conn->senderId = $value;
            else if($key == "receiverId")
                $conn->receiverId = $value;
        } 

        $chatManager = new ChatMananger($conn->senderId, $conn->receiverId);

        $conn->chatId = $chatManager->getChatId();

        $this->clients->attach($conn, $conn->chatId);

        echo PHP_EOL."New connection! ({$conn->resourceId}) chatId ({$conn->chatId})";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }

}
```

`ChatMananger.php`

```
namespace MyApp;

require_once '/var/www/libs/DBConnection.php';

class ChatMananger
{
     const DEFAULT_CHAT_SIZE = 5;
     const DEFAULT_CHAT_TYPE = 1;

     private $dbConnection;
     private $chatId;
     private $senderId;
     private $receiverId;
     private $type = self::DEFAULT_CHAT_TYPE;

      public function __construct($senderId, $receiverId)
      {   
       $this->dbConnection = \DBConnection::getDBConnection();  

       $this->senderId = $senderId;
       $this->receiverId = $receiverId;     
       }

    public function getDBConnection()
    {
            return $this->dbConnection; 
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that in the method `onOpen` I use:

```
$chatManager = new ChatMananger($conn->senderId, $conn->receiverId);
```

For this code I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ChatMananger' not found in /var/www/soFitTest/chat/src/MyApp/Chat.php on line 37
```

Comment: Can you add the content of your ChatManager ?

Answer (score 4):

Import ChatManager first ([Using namespaces in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)):

```
include_once __DIR__.'/ChatMananger.php';

use MyApp\ChatManager;
```

And later use it like this:

```
$chatManager = new ChatMananger(1, 1);
```

Comment: I get this error: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class ChatMananger in /var/www/soFitTest/chat/src/MyApp/ChatMananger.php on line 6

Comment: Declare the namespace MyApp in your ChatManager class:

Comment: Adding the name space to the class, solved it, thanks!

Comment: I do not see use MyApp\ChatManager in Chat class;

Comment: I added it and I stll get PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyApp\ChatManager' not found in /var/www/soFitTest/chat/src/MyApp/ChatMananger.php on line 37

Comment: Can you provide the updated versions of Chat and ChatManager?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72140/discussion-between-vladislav-and-dasdasd).

Comment: Please rename all the occurrences of ChatMananger to ChatManager including the file name

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is this line:

```
private $type = ChatManager::DEFAULT_CHAT_TYPE;
```

Change it to:

```
private $type = self::DEFAULT_CHAT_TYPE;
```

---

Also:

```
$chatManager = new \ChatMananger(1, 1);
```

should probably be:

```
$chatManager = new MyApp\ChatManager(1, 1);
```

(if I understand your namespace structure properly)

---

Similarly, your ChatManager class should declare a namespace above it (for consistency). The complete file would look as follows:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp;

require_once 'DBConnection.php';

class ChatManager
{
    const DEFAULT_CHAT_SIZE = 5;
    const DEFAULT_CHAT_TYPE = 1;

    private $dbConnection;
    private $chatId;
    private $senderId;
    private $receiverId;
    private $type = self::DEFAULT_CHAT_TYPE;

    public function __construct($senderId, $receiverId)
    {
        $this->dbConnection = DBConnection::getDBConnection();

        $this->senderId = $senderId;
        $this->receiverId = $receiverId;
    }

    public function getDBConnection()
    {
        return $this->dbConnection;
    }
}
```