# Getting fatal error while running the php file

Tags: php

I am getting the following error while running the below file using this `php /var/www/html/abcd.com/public_html/beta/corn_user.php` command in terminal.

> Error:

```
PHP warning : include_once(var/www/html/koolfeedback.com/public_html/beta/admin/dbcon/DBConnection.php) failed to open strem.

PHP fatal error: class DBConnection is not found.
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
include_once 'var/www/html/koolfeedback.com/public_html/beta/admin/dbcon/DBConnection.php';
include_once'/var/www/html/koolfeedback.com/public_html/beta/fcmClass.php';
$protocol = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "off") ? "https" : "http";
//$cimagepath = $protocol . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/beta/admin/promotion/";
//$imagepath = $protocol . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/beta/admin/uploads/";
$dbobj = new DBConnection();
$db = $dbobj->connectFront();
$cnt =0;
$count=1;
$db->kf_test_cron->insert(array("key"=>"hello"));
?>
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class not found, using include\_once in namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830227/class-not-found-using-include-once-in-namespace)

Comment: you forgot the `/` at the beginning of the path

Answer (score 0):

change from

```
include_once 'var/www/html/koolfeedback.com/public_html/beta/admin/dbcon/DBConnection.php';
include_once'/var/www/html/koolfeedback.com/public_html/beta/fcmClass.php';
```

to

```
include_once 'admin/dbcon/DBConnection.php';
include_once 'fcmClass.php';
```

Comment: i did as per you but got again error.`php fatal error:require_once ():failed opening required` and this error is coming inside `DBConnection.php` file.

Comment: so now you are getting new error instead of class DBConnection is not found. right?

Comment: change include_once'fcmClass.php'; to include_once 'fcmClass.php'; add space between include_once and 'frmClass.php'

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting that error because the file you want to `include` can not be found as the url could not be resolved.

Include your file relative to your current php file that is `corn_user.php`

So, make the below changes:

```
include_once ('admin/dbcon/DBConnection.php');
include_once ('fcmClass.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the include line beginning with the first directory inside the root directory of your web server.

For instance, if your root is `htdocs` (ignoring anything that comes before that), and the file is inside `'includes'`, then write: `include_once('includes/foo.html')`. Includes in php always start by assuming the root `'/'`, and take it from the uri path, not the local file path.

Also, if you intended you htdocs root to be `/beta/`, make sure this is declared in your config file. Otherwise it will treat your root directory as 'html'.